# Only 1 file gets uploaded even if multiple files have been selected

Tags: jquery-file-upload, blueimp

When I click on my file input button and I select two files in the file dialog, on the `add` callback I see that the value of `data.files.length` is 2. Just before calling `data.submit()`, the value is still 2. However, only 1 file is uploaded.
Why?

Relevant configuration options used are:

```
autoUpload: false,
singleFileUploads: false,
```

jQuery File Upload is attached to...

```
<input id="fileupload" type="file" name="attachment" multiple>
```

Answer (score 0):

The configuration option you are looking for is MaxNumberOfFiles.

```
// sets maximum number of files...
$("form#formid").fileupload('option', 'maxNumberOfFiles', 10);
```

You might also would like to change the input to following

```
<input id="fileuploadinput" type="file" name="attachment[]" multiple>
// Only reason to change id is so that it may not conflict. You may not have to do it though.
```

Hopefully this should solve your problem if no other issues are there.